# ID Buffer THREE JS WEBGL Non Photorealistic Rendering Edge Detection

Tags: three.js

I'm working on some screen space shaders using THREE.JS and GLSL. I'd like to both render a "diffuse" buffer with per object materials/textures AND render an "ID" buffer where each object has a unique color for object edge detection. This would also be really useful for object picking as some of the THREE.JS examples show.

I am already using Scene.overrideMaterial to render normal buffers (and some other cool stuff) but haven't figured out a way to do something similar for an ID buffer. Is there something like this that exists? Seems useful enough that it would be likely. Have other people developed solutions to this problem? Maybe by mapping an objects UUID to a color value?

-----> EDIT
Here is my attempt using this example:
https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_instances_gpu.html

I'm not concerned with selection at this point, regardless this isn't working. I think I may be setting up onBeforeRender() incorrectly. Any help on this?

Thanks!

```
initPieces = function(geometry){
    ...
    //set id Color to unique color
    //for picking will use setHex(i) method
    m.userData.idColor = material.color;

    ...

    m.onBeforeRender = function (){
        if(Viewer._scene.overrideMaterial){
                if(Viewer._scene.overrideMaterial._name == "id"){
                    var updateList = [];

                    var u = scene.overrideMaterial.uniforms;
                    //picking color in user data
                    var d = this.userData;

                    //Is this just equivalent to checking whether this is the picking material?
                    if(u.idColor){
                        u.idColor.value = (d.idColor);
                        // u.needsUpdate = true;
                        updateList.push("idColor");
                    }

                    //Don't understand what this is doing
                    //Throws "WebGL INVALID_OPERATION: uniformMatrix4fv: location is not from current program"
                    if (updateList.length){
                        var materialProperties = renderer.properties.get(material);

                        if( materialProperties.program){
                            var gl = renderer.getContext();
                            var p = materialProperties.program;
                            gl.useProgram( p.program );
                            var pu = p.getUniforms();

                            updateList.forEach(function(name){
                                pu.setValue( gl, name, u[name].value);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Doesn't show onBeforeRender set as I expected?
        console.log(m);

        ...
    }
    ...
}

...

function render(scene, camera){
    ...
    scene.overrideMaterial = getMaterial("id");
    renderer.render(scene, camera, getTarget("id"));
    scene.overrideMaterial = null;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there would be a suitable way to do this using `Scene.overridematerial`, seeing as it is one material rather than one that could be modified per object in the scene, that would be less hassle then just doing as the GPU picking example does (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gpu#webgl_interactive_cubes_gpu) and having a separate scene with the colour of the materials on the objects set via `Color.setHex(UUID)`.

Comment: Just create a `ShaderMaterial` for your `Scene.overrideMaterial`, with a custom uniform used to set the object color. Then, for each object, assign its `onBeforeRender` function to check if `Scene.overrideMaterial` is set, and if so set the uniform to that object's color value. You'll also need to tell the `ShaderMaterial` the uniforms need updated (`material.uniformsNeedUpdate = true;`), and it should process each one correctly. Try it out, and update your post with your attempt, and we can help you through any errors that hold you back.

Comment: Thanks @TheJim01 I will try this this weekend and let you know!

Comment: Haven't had so much time to work on this recently, but I found this example which seems to be doing the same thing. Working through how I can apply this to my case.

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=gpu#webgl_interactive_instances_gpu